# What do the (+) and (-) operators after the divergence symbol ($\nabla$) mean?

Tags: functions, definition, divergence-operator

What $+$ and $-$ after $\nabla$ mean? For example, from NMF with the beta-divergence,

"Let $θ$ be a coefficient of W or H. As will be seen later, when using the β-divergence the derivative $\nabla_θ{D(θ)}$ of the criterion $D(V|WH)$ with respect to $θ$ can be expressed as the difference of two nonnegative functions such that
$$\nabla_θ{D(θ)} = \nabla_θ^+{D(θ)} - \nabla_θ^-{D(θ)}$$

May you provide easy example regarding this?

Comment: It's obviously the positive and negative parts of $\nabla_θ{D(θ)}$. Given a real-valued function $f$ you can set $f^+(x) = \max(f(x), 0)$ and $f^-(x) = \max(-f(x), 0)$. Then $f^+, f^- \geq 0$ and $f = f^+ - f^-$.

Comment: For example if $f(x) = x^2$ and $x=3$ $$f^+(x)=max(9,0)  \textrm{ and }  f^−(x)=max(−9,0)$$ May you explain a bit more what happens after this please?

Comment: You get $f^+(3) = 9$ and $f^-(3) = 0$. Both are nonnegative, and you have $f(3) = f^+(3) - f^-(3)$.

Comment: It's however better if you look at a whole function that takes both positive and negative values, e.g. $\sin x$ or $x^2 - 1$.